# How to find a solution to a bug with ionic?

Tags: cordova, ionic-framework

I have an application using ionic. Sometimes, but no always, the application crash (I cannot do anything, the application is blocked). In the web server (ionic serve), the computer is working a lot (The fan come on). I have to restart the server, I cannot just actualise the page, is completely blocked. When I test in a device, the problem is the same, but I have to close the application and reopen.

I cannot reproduce the error, sometimes come, sometimes not.

The problem is that the console says nothing, no error. I have tested to do a console.log in each part of my application, but nothing is printed before the application crash.

Have you an idea of how can I act to find the error?
Thanks

Comment: Is there any API calling in app?

Comment: mmh, yes I'm using jQuery, d3, lodhash, eventemitter